# QRegularExpression - How to extract string from between two <ca> tags?

Tags: regex, qt, qregularexpression

I am trying to get the text within multiple tags as following:

**Text File:**

```
Internal Auto-Configured Settings File
________________________________________
(( Do not attempt to edit it manually ))
________________________________________
# Saved certifications:
<ca>
Text which I want to extract
</ca>
...
<cert>Another text I want to extract</cert>
...
```

---

In my code I open the previous file and read its content & store it into a `QString`. So far I've done the following without any success:

```
QRegularExpression regex("<ca>(.*)</ca>", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(content);
QString ca = match.captured(1);

qDebug() << ca;
qDebug() << "\n\nDone!!";
```

<< Also did the same for `<cert>` but I get an empty string for both.

Comment: Use SingleLine option if any. The naming is terrible, but the single line option makes `.` matches new line characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption`, use [`QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtcore/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum). The problem is due to the fact that `.` doesn't match new line character in default mode.

Citing the documentation:

> The dot metacharacter (`.`) in the pattern string is allowed to match any character in the subject string, including newlines (normally, the dot does not match newlines). This option corresponds to the `/s` modifier in Perl regular expressions.

Make sure that `</ca>` only appear once in the input.

If that is not the case, modify your expression a bit:

```
"<ca>(.*?)</ca>"
```

This makes the quantifier lazy (instead of the default greedy), and causes it to match the closest closing tag `</ca>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also if I want to get the inner text along with the tags ( <ca>with</ca> ), how?

Comment: Shouldn't your code already do this? The whole thing is available as the main match `captured()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ca>(.*?)<\/ca>|<cert>(.*?)<\/cert>
```

You can try this.Do no forget to add flag `s` or `DOTALL`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/30

Comment: Ok if I want to capture it with the two tags, how?